# Generating LLVM code to link against OS-specific implementations (pthread)

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir

I’m building a programming language with an LLVM back-end, and developing support for multithreading.

To figure out how to make the appropriate function calls in LLVM, I’m compiling the following simple C program:

```c
#include <pthread.h>

int main() {
  pthread_t my_thread;

  pthread_mutex_t my_mutex;
  pthread_mutex_init(&my_mutex, NULL);

  pthread_mutex_lock(&my_mutex);
  pthread_mutex_unlock(&my_mutex);

  pthread_join(my_thread, NULL);

  return 0;
}
```

When I run `clang -S -emit-llvm example.c`, I get a LLVM IR like the following:

```
%struct._opaque_pthread_t = type { i64, %struct.__darwin_pthread_handler_rec*, [8176 x i8] }
%struct.__darwin_pthread_handler_rec = type { void (i8*)*, i8*, %struct.__darwin_pthread_handler_rec* }
%struct._opaque_pthread_mutex_t = type { i64, [56 x i8] }
%struct._opaque_pthread_mutexattr_t = type { i64, [8 x i8] }

define i32 @main() #0 {
  %1 = alloca i32, align 4
  %2 = alloca %struct._opaque_pthread_t*, align 8
  %3 = alloca %struct._opaque_pthread_mutex_t, align 8
  store i32 0, i32* %1, align 4
  %4 = call i32 @pthread_mutex_init(%struct._opaque_pthread_mutex_t* noundef %3, %struct._opaque_pthread_mutexattr_t* noundef null)
  %5 = call i32 @pthread_mutex_lock(%struct._opaque_pthread_mutex_t* noundef %3)
  %6 = call i32 @pthread_mutex_unlock(%struct._opaque_pthread_mutex_t* noundef %3)
  %7 = load %struct._opaque_pthread_t*, %struct._opaque_pthread_t** %2, align 8
  %8 = call i32 @"\01_pthread_join"(%struct._opaque_pthread_t* noundef %7, i8** noundef null)
  ret i32 0
}

declare i32 @pthread_mutex_init(%struct._opaque_pthread_mutex_t* noundef, %struct._opaque_pthread_mutexattr_t* noundef) #1
declare i32 @pthread_mutex_lock(%struct._opaque_pthread_mutex_t* noundef) #1
declare i32 @pthread_mutex_unlock(%struct._opaque_pthread_mutex_t* noundef) #1
declare i32 @"\01_pthread_join"(%struct._opaque_pthread_t* noundef, i8** noundef) #1
```

Although the structs declared at the top are called things like “`_opaque_pthread_mutex_t`,” they don’t *look* very opaque; in fact, they seem to reference explicitly the internal layout of `pthread` objects, and even include platform-specific labels (“`darwin`”). Using `clang` to compile the same program on a different system produces very different results.

**For a compiler I’m implementing myself in OCaml, how can I know what LLVM IR I need to generate?** Or are these platform-specific definitions unnecessary? How does `clang` know the internal format of `pthread` objects in order to make these definitions?

Answer (score 0):

The definitions of pthread-related types go from `pthread.h` header, they are declared there and this is where clang takes them from.

In general, pthread calls are not target-neutral, so you'd need to have some kind of platform-specific support layer in order to utilize them. The exact layout of pthread-related objects is in general target- and implementation-specific, therefore you'd need to abstract it out one way or another.